# On Premise ADFS 3.0 OAuth2 WebApi + AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, adfs3.0

I am completely lost on this, any help would be appreciated.

When I click `Login` through my client app from angularJS, I get redirect to :

```
https://adfs.dev5.local/adfs/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=09c9a8a2-6bf1-427d-89ba-45c2c02bb9fc&resource=urn%3Awebapi%3Atest&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44326%2F&state=52e4aa10-f082-4ee6-8823-543ec6e4dce4&client-request-id=e2751f34-f7db-41f4-8c1d-4463e2dca48b&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.15&nonce=93039780-99f6-4efc-8b1b-58aa92df9f82
```

Which is fine and all, I am able to enter my email + password. Once I login I get redirect to:

```
https://localhost:44326/?code=OLCE2LJVeU2Zy2-7Q4oIMg.6Pr0vZgW1QhBAMQoUlgIKAdAsno.q4scWy_ZFQHQEz08M3gU3KJU4NhXdimZiMpgSGBQ8xKN8BLK0Qoe1m1cK5TA2WLLyA14SlnnfA4yHEp5_pTWrIOYNrvOVzNiGU0Zkie-7ae2D1_3U1E1rTmLUTprIadU4gLmo2CeMHkM8gumS285wKsRsMpXVLcavjgjyRM3XoWXSDSP96_eeMgq1osQ1M5170rrGOh_DVqKG-xYnKk5PEC7cWikaR_pxCvwvayLMV0VQIIyq1GJ3CvgK8sWFJGdY3jz247Bh8RPH9-t2_Jz3_7wyqvfvfquAY8tQxElEN1IEoPMOwVdjfBgNlZlw7vtAo79jdH1C_TRNUC5T3IrXw&state=52e4aa10-f082-4ee6-8823-543ec6e4dce4&client-request-id=e2751f34-f7db-41f4-8c1d-4463e2dca48b
```

This is where I am confused I don't think it's suppose to redirect me to that..., I know that I need to POST this some how to get the token, but how? I use Postman and I was able to get the access token, but what I don't understand is how do my WebAPI translate this to access token?

I am using ADFS 3.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Setup ADFS:

```
Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name MyWebAPI -Identifier urn:webapi:test -IssuanceAuthorizationRules '=> issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", Value = "true");' -IssuanceTransformRules 'c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"] => issue(claim = c);'
```

Add Client:

```
Add-ADFSClient -Name "client" -ClientId "09c9a8a2-6bf1-427d-89ba-45c2c02bb9fc" -RedirectUri "https://localhost:44326/"
```

Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
    new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        MetadataEndpoint = "https://adfs.dev5.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
        }
    });
```

webconfig for audience:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ida:Audience" value="https://localhost:44326/" />
</appSettings>
```

AngularJS adal setup:

```
adalProvider.init(
    {
        instance: 'https://adfs.dev5.local/', 
        tenant: 'adfs',
        clientId: '09c9a8a2-6bf1-427d-89ba-45c2c02bb9fc',
        redirectUri: 'https://localhost:44326/'
        //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
    },
    $httpProvider
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these Postman [samples](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/search/label/Postman).

You'll see I did each flow but for ADFS 4.0 which has the full OpenID Connect / OAuth stack.

ADFS 3.0 only has auth. code grant for confidential clients.

Once you have the code for the authorize endpoint, you need to send it to the token endpoint to get the actual token.

There's a good example [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).

Also be aware that js clients normally use the implicit flow.

Comment: Thanks, you led me to a solution, regarding that ADFS 3.0 only does `code` grant. Took me days debugging + trial and error, finally was able to come to a solution it will work for me. The idea is to use Identity Server, with that I was able to use ADFS 3 as external login and Identity Server for OAuth.

Comment: @12seconds This post is a great help to me, but what do you mean to use "Identity Server" for OAuth? I'm trying to run a Dynamics CRM (On Premise, ADFS 3.0) web service from a AWS Lambda function, with the redirect URI being another Lambda via the AWS API Gateway, but ADFS doesn't appear to like my redirect (localhost works fine). Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @Heckflosse_230, ADFS 3.0 doesn't support OAuth 2.0 tokens. So to get around that I built my own [Identity Server 4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) (You can also use Identity Server 3 if you wish) around ADFS 3.0 which act as a "middle man". So it goes like this: Identity Server > redirects to ADFS 3.0 Login > returns back SAML token to identity server which gets translated to OAuth token.

Comment: Thank you 12Seconds! I'll look into Identity Server.